# Quartus 2 - No output dependent on input / Output pins are stuck

Tags: verilog, mips32, quartus

I am trying to implement a single cycle MIPS processor via Quartus 2 and faced with these warnings. The clk is the input of my main module and it says it does not effect any outputs. Also my main module's outputs are stuck at VCC/GND. I suppose that it is related to clk signal. I think that the first warning's cause is I did not write anything to instruction memory so you can ignore it.

So what is the common reasons of these warnings? Any ideas to solve ?

**Warning (10858): Verilog HDL warning at instruction_memory.v(7): object instructions used but never assigned.

Warning (13024): Output pins are stuck at VCC or GND

           Warning (21074): Design contains 1 input pin(s) that do not drive logic

                                                                          Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "clk"**

My Test Bench :

```
`timescale 1ps/1ps
module mips32_testbench();

wire [31:0] instr;
wire [31:0] R;
wire [31:0] PC;
reg [31:0] counter;
reg  clk,clk2;

mips32_single_cycle i0 (.PC_new(PC) ,.instruction(instr) ,  .result(R) , .clk(clk) );

always
begin
    #8 clk = ~clk;
end

always
begin
    #24 clk2 = ~clk2;
end

initial
begin
    clk = 0;
    clk2 = 0;
    counter = -1;
    $readmemb("registers.mem", i0.MR0.registers);
    $readmemb("instructions.tv", i0.IM1.instructions);
    $readmemb("datas.mem", i0.ALU1.LW1.DM1.datas);
end

always @(posedge clk2)
begin
    //empty
end

always @(negedge clk2)
begin
    $display("PC = %5b \n", PC[4:0]);

    $display("opcode = %6b, rs = %5b, rt = %5b, rd= %5b, immediate = %16b , address = %26b ,funct = %6b \n",instr[31:26], instr[25:21], instr[20:16], instr[15:11], instr[15:0] , instr[25:0] ,instr[5:0] );

    $display("result = %32b \n", i0.result);

    counter <= counter + 1 ;

    if(PC === 32'b00000000000000000000000000001011)begin
        $writememb("regLast.mem",i0.MR1.registers);
        $writememb("dataLast.mem",i0.ALU1.LW1.DM1.datas);
        $display("%d tests completed. \n",counter);
        $finish;
    end
end

endmodule
```

My top module:

```
module mips32_single_cycle(PC_new , instruction , result , clk);

input clk;
output [31:0] instruction ;
output [31:0] result;
output [31:0] PC_new;

wire [2:0] select_IJtype, select_Rtype;
wire [31:0] rs , rt , tempr0 , tempr1 ,tempr2;
wire [31:0] R0,R1,R;
wire [31:0] Program_Counter;
wire [4:0] result_register ;
wire [7:0] data_address;
wire data_write_enable;
wire write_enable;

//Unnecessary temp wires
wire t0,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14,t15,t16,t17,t18,t19,t20,t21;
wire zero;
wire [31:0] tr1,tr2,tr3,tr4;

//PC read
mips_registers MR0 ( tr1 , tr2, 32'b00000000000000000000000000000000, 5'b00000, 5'b00000, 5'b00000, 1'b0, clk ,Program_Counter , 32'b00000000000000000000000000000000 , 1'b0);

//Instruction read
instruction_memory  IM1 ( instruction, Program_Counter, clk );

//Creating select signals
control_unit CU1   (select_Rtype, instruction[5:0]);
control_unit_2 CU2 (select_IJtype, instruction[31:26]);

//Pull register source
mips_registers MR1 ( rs , rt, 32'b00000000000000000000000000000000, instruction[25:21], instruction[20:16], instruction[15:11], 1'b0, clk ,tr3 , 32'b00000000000000000000000000000000 , 1'b0);

//Perform the task
alu32_2 ALU1 (data_address, PC_new ,R0 ,select_Rtype ,select_IJtype ,rs ,rt ,instruction , Program_Counter ,clk);

//if this expression is equal to 1 then the instruction we have is sltu: 
//select_Rtype[2]select_Rtype[1]'select_Rtype[0]'instruction[0]instruction[31]'instruction[30]'instruction[29]'instruction[28]'instruction[27]'instruction[26]'
not NOT1 (t0 , instruction[31]);
not NOT2 (t1 , instruction[30]);
not NOT3 (t2 , instruction[29]);
not NOT4 (t3 , instruction[28]);
not NOT5 (t4 , instruction[27]);
not NOT6 (t5 , instruction[26]);
not NOT7 (t6 , select_Rtype[1]);
not NOT8 (t7 , select_Rtype[0]);

and AND1 (t8 , t6 , select_Rtype[2]);
and AND2 (t9 , t8 , t7);
and AND3 (t10 , t9 , instruction[0]);
and AND4 (t11 , t10 , t0);
and AND5 (t12 , t11 , t1);
and AND6 (t13 , t12 , t2);
and AND7 (t14 , t13 , t3);
and AND8 (t15 , t14 , t4);
and AND9 (t16 , t15 , t5);

sltu32 SLTU1 (zero ,R1 ,R0);

mux21_32bit M0(result , R0 , R1 , t16);

//If write_enable equals to '0' ,it means that instruction is sw ,j,beq.So write enable signal become 0.
//write_enable = select_IJtype[2]select_IJtype[0]
and AND10 (t19 , select_IJtype[0] , select_IJtype[2] );
not NOT9  (write_enable , t19 );

//R type result ==> rd register 
//I type result ==> rt register
//If below expression is equal to 1, it means the instruction is I or J type.
//select_IJtype[0]+select_IJtype[1]+select_IJtype[2]
or OR1 (t17 , select_IJtype[0] , select_IJtype[1]);
or OR2 (t18 , t17 , select_IJtype[2]);

mux21_1bit M1 (result_register[4] , instruction[15] , instruction[20] ,t18);
mux21_1bit M2 (result_register[3] , instruction[14] , instruction[19] ,t18);
mux21_1bit M3 (result_register[2] , instruction[13] , instruction[18] ,t18);
mux21_1bit M4 (result_register[1] , instruction[12] , instruction[17] ,t18);
mux21_1bit M5 (result_register[0] , instruction[11] , instruction[16] ,t18);

//Write back to registers
mips_registers MR2 ( tempr0 , tempr1, result, instruction[25:21], instruction[20:16], result_register, write_enable, clk ,tr4 , PC_new , 1'b1);

//If sw then need to write data_memory
//sw means = select_IJtype[2]select_IJtype[0]select_IJtype[1]'
not NOT10 (t20 , select_IJtype[1]);
and AND11 ( data_write_enable , t20 , t19);

data_memory DM1 (tempr2 , result , data_address , data_write_enable , clk);

endmodule
```

**EDIT** : I added the modules which takes clock signal:

There is a file contains 32 bit registers' data and the PC counter.This module supposed to do the i/o operations with it.

```
module mips_registers( read_data_1, read_data_2, write_data, read_reg_1, read_reg_2, write_reg, signal_reg_write, clk ,PC_read , PC_write ,PC_write_enable);

output reg[31:0] read_data_1, read_data_2 ,PC_read;
input [31:0] write_data , PC_write;
input [4:0] read_reg_1, read_reg_2, write_reg;
input signal_reg_write, PC_write_enable ,clk;

reg [31:0] registers [32:0];


wire [5:0] rr1,rr2,wr1;

zeroextend_1bit ZE1_1 (rr1 , read_reg_1);
zeroextend_1bit ZE1_2 (rr2 , read_reg_2);
zeroextend_1bit ZE1_3 (wr1 , write_reg);

always@ (posedge clk) begin
    if(1 == signal_reg_write)begin
        registers[wr1] <= write_data;
    end
    if(1 == PC_write_enable)begin
        registers[6'b100000] <= PC_write;
    end
end

always@ (negedge clk) begin
    read_data_1 <= registers[rr1];
    read_data_2 <= registers[rr2];
    PC_read <= registers[6'b100000];
end

endmodule
```

There is an instruction memory 32 x 32.This module supposed to outputs only the wanted instruction from memory.

```
module instruction_memory ( read_instruction, PC, clk );

output reg[31:0] read_instruction;
input [31:0] PC;
input clk;

reg [31:0] instructions [31:0];

always@ (negedge clk) begin
    read_instruction <= instructions[PC[4:0]];
end

endmodule
```

Here is the data memory module:

```
module data_memory ( read_data , write_data, memoryaddress, signal_write_data, clk );

output reg[31:0] read_data;
input [31:0] write_data;
input [7:0] memoryaddress;
input clk , signal_write_data;

reg [31:0] datas [255:0];

always@ (posedge clk) begin
    if(1 == signal_write_data)begin
        datas[memoryaddress] <= write_data;
    end
end

always@ (negedge clk) begin
    read_data <= datas[memoryaddress];
end

endmodule
```

Here is my ALU. loadword,storeword and nextPC use memory modules inside,thats why they take clock signal:

```
module alu32_2 (data_address ,PC_new , R ,select_Rtype ,select_IJtype ,rs ,rt ,instr ,PC ,clk);
input [31:0] rs,rt;
input [31:0] instr;
input [2:0]  select_IJtype, select_Rtype;
input [31:0] PC;
input clk;

output [31:0] R , PC_new;
output [7:0] data_address;

wire [31:0] I0,I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7;
wire ZANDI,ZORI,ZADDIU;
wire OADDIU;
wire CADDIU;
wire [31:0] EXT;
wire overflow;
wire zero;

zeroextendimm  EXT1 (EXT , instr[15:0] );


Rtype_alu_controller  ROC1 (overflow , zero ,I0 ,select_Rtype ,rs ,rt ,instr[10:5]);
and32                 AND1 (ZANDI,I1,rs,EXT);
or32                  OR1  (ZORI,I2,rs,EXT);
add32                 ADD1 (OADDIU,ZADDIU,CADDIU,I3,rs,EXT,1'b0);
loadword              LW1  (I4,instr[20:16],rs,instr[15:0],clk);
storeword             SW1  (I5,data_address,instr[20:16],rs,instr[15:0],clk);
beq                     BEQ1 (I6,PC,rs,rt,instr[15:0]);
j                     J1   (I7,PC,instr[25:0]);

mux81_32bit M1 (R,I0,I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,select_IJtype);
nextPC NPC (PC_new ,I6 , I7 , PC ,select_IJtype ,clk);

endmodule
```

Comment: either you failed to compile your test bench code with the corresponding $readmem, or the file does not initialize all the memory. Also, what is the point having the `clk` input if you never use it?

Comment: I do not get the point you focus on.I am using the `clk` input but it says it does not drive any logic, it is the problem here.Compiler does not give any errors but gives warnings I described above.The files initialize memory(I check that.) but the modules with `clk` input do not work correctly. Did I do something wrong in clock usage?

Comment: unused clk makes me think that you could have logical issues or an unfinished module.  I do not know if it is true or not, just a red flag.

Comment: If there is an unfinished module then wouldn't there be a compilation error?And if you want I can upload my hole project if these module are not enough to clarify the problem. @Serge

Comment: You probably have a misnamed pin in your constraints. Check to see that your constraints file has the pin named "clk."

Answer (score 1):

Before answering the question, imagine you have a PC, or any board with a processor. Clear any type of memory it has, including boot memory and anything on chip or on board that can store data in it. Now turn the power on. What happened? Now apply the clock, do you see any change to the function of the system? I think at this point you have the answer to your question.

**Short answer: As you cannot change the result without initializing your instruction/data memory properly, any change in your `clk` does not lead to a change in your outputs, so the Quartus software gives those warnings**.

At this point, I will tell you when Quartus 2 or Quartus Prime gives those warnings:

**13024: The Quartus software gives this warning when there are outputs that do never change (given the present system and any possible input)**

**21074: When any change in an input does not effect the result, or state of a logic (as the name suggests)**

**15610: as the name suggests**

Now let me start with the reasons:

I tried to synthesize your instruction memory, it synthesizes, but the **Quartus software assumes the memory is filled with 0's** and it gives the following warnings (as expected):

```
Warning (13024): Output pins are stuck at VCC or GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[0]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[1]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[2]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[3]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[4]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[5]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[6]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[7]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[8]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[9]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[10]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[11]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[12]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[13]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[14]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[15]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[16]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[17]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[18]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[19]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[20]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[21]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[22]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[23]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[24]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[25]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[26]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[27]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[28]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[29]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[30]" is stuck at GND
Warning (13410): Pin "read_instruction[31]" is stuck at GND
Warning (21074): Design contains 33 input pin(s) that do not drive logic
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[0]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[1]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[2]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[3]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[4]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[5]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[6]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[7]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[8]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[9]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[10]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[11]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[12]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[13]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[14]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[15]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[16]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[17]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[18]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[19]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[20]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[21]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[22]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[23]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[24]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[25]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[26]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[27]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[28]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[29]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[30]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "PC[31]"
Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "clk"
```

So, what does it mean? 
As it was suggested in comments, most common reason might have been, possibly you have not used the input in your logic, obviously it is not the case for you. 
**But, even if clk and PC inputs of your instruction memory were used in its logic,  we have the same warnings, because every single bit of instruction memory is initialized to 0 by default (although you never did it), as a result any value for PC regardless of which `negedge clk` you are, it outputs the same `read_instruction` which is always zero and obviously constant.** The Quartus software sees this and gives the warnings.

Now check your data memory, have you initialized it? **NO!** So your data memory is also full of 0's at the beginning (instruction memory is always full of 0's). As it can be seen from your design, your processor does not have any input other than `clk`.

You have memories initially filled with zero, and start your system, what happens change happens to your result (try replacing all instructions you use with 0's additionally data memory starts with 0's)?